# Storing Google credentials

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm writing an application that needs to log into a given Google Analytics account and using the Google Analytics API perform various calls.

Obviously storing details inside a MySQL database is a bad idea.

How would I get around this? Any ideas or considerations I need to take into account?

Comment: Probably save credentials in .ini file and put it before webroot so that it won't be accessible from HTTP protocol.

Comment: Providing you encrypt the passwords with MD5 or SHA1 then I don't see any problem in storing the details in a MySQL database? For all login systems the passwords are generally stored in the database.

Comment: The problem with encrypting is that when I call google's API the credentials are going to be wrong, as they're encrypted. As for having an .ini file, I should mention that I'll need to update the details and I'll need to add multiple sites (thus meaning more analytic accounts).